# Aggregate a table's multiple rows into a single column, then join to an existing select statement to preserve the one to one relationship

Tags: sql, join, impala

How to aggregate a table's multiple rows into a single column, then join to an existing select statement to preserve the one to one relationship?

I have an SQL statement in Impala which joins two tables on `INC`. There is one `INC` for each of the tables field's so the join creates a one to one relationship between the two tables. The SQL for joining Table `TBL_A` to `TBL_B` is as follows:

```
SELECT  INC_TBL_A, CITY_TBL_B
FROM    TBL_A.INC_TBL_A        
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_B 
        ON 
            TBL_A.INC_TBL_A = TBL_B.TBL_B.INC 
            AND TBL_B.TBL_B.XYZ = 17000
```

Output:

```
INC_TBLE_A  CITY_TBL_B
INC1        SYDNEY
INC2        HONG KONG
INC3        LONDON
```

I need to introduce another table, which has many values (`MANY_FIELD_C`) for one INC (`INC_C`):

```
INC_C   MANY_FIELD_C
INC1    , A
INC1    , B
INC1    C
INC1    C
INC1    , D
INC1    , E
INC2    34W
INC2    c
INC3    ~5
INC3    ^d
```

How do I roll up field `MANY_FIELD_C` into  `ROLLED UP_C`?

```
INC_C   ROLLED UP_C
INC1    , A , B C C , D , E
INC2    34W c
INC3    ~5 ^d
```

Comment: You can use listagg in your subquery and then join it back to your main table

Comment: Apart from the code for joining the two tables, can you share your best coding attempt at solving this problem?

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? What do the parts of what you wrote have to do with it? By "I'd like" do you mean "How do I"? "the crux" of what & in what way"? By "crux" do you mean "goal"? [mre] [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: listagg isnt available in impala. OP  used group_concat - which is correct

Comment: collect list is for hive mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this through the `GROUP_CONCAT` function:

```
SELECT INC_C,
        GROUP_CONCAT(MANY_FIELD_C) AS ROLLED UP_C
FROM    TBL_C
GROUP BY INC_C
```